# Easy way to set pre-trained weights in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-layers

Is there an easy way to set pretrained weights to a tensorflow layer? (w/o keras)

In keras it's easy as `model.set_weights(...)` or `layer.set_weights(...)` - but I'm breaking my head around this for more than a day in tf, and can't seem to find anything that works.

Comment: You can use [`tf.assign`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/assign) so assign value for individual variables.

Comment: If I use `tf.layers.dense` how do I know the name of the weight variables?

Comment: @DavidRefaeli Where are you copying the data from?

Comment: @cookiemonster you are right, the solution there works. Thanks, sorry I didn't find it by my own but I searched for more than a few hours.

Comment: @carobnodrvo from a matlab matrix file